# Reading two Ys on a line which have been split

Tags: python

I have split two the lines at the commas(taking them away)
All I am left with is the name of the Lennings,George,Y,Y but since the it has been split, I cant read the Ys as part of same line. I know this is very simple but I am incredibly confused(also its reading from a file).

```
empFile = "Employee.txt"
confFile = "confpacks.txt"

confFile = open("confpacks.txt", "r")
packsread = confFile.readlines()

readFile = open("Employee.txt", "r")
records = readFile.readlines()

    for line in records:
      line = line[:-1]
      fields = line.split(",")

      for field in fields:
        print(field, end=" , ")



        if field == "Y":
          print("Only attended one day therefore recieves " + packsread[0])
```

expected output

if there is the the name and two Y Y so

```
John, Steward, Y , Y, attended both days.
```

if there is the the name and one Y so

```
John, Steward,Y attended one day
```

if there are no Ys at all

```
John, Steward, did not attend any days
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can count `Y`s in the end of the line and add the message based on the counter:

```
for line in file:
    line = line.strip()
    fields = line.split(",")

    count = 0
    for v in reversed(fields):
        if v == 'Y':
            count += 1
        else:
            break

    print(', '.join(fields), end=', ')

    if not count:
        print('did not attend any days')
    elif count == 1:
        print('attended one day')
    else:
        print('attended both days')
```